# Air SQLite:how to use the date type?

Tags: air

```
var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
stat.sqlConnection = connection;
stat.text = "INSERT INTO names (id, name,myDate) VALUES (117, 'tarek', 3/10/2015)";
stat.execute();
```

i use air sqlite, why the date can't be inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the myDate field was created as a DATE type, you have to cast the date you're inserting by using the SQLite date() function and you should use the format YYYY-MM-DD. This works:

```
INSERT INTO names (id, name, myDate) VALUES (117, 'tarek', date('2015-10-03'))
```